# trying to use time.js with a for loop in javascript outputs only the final value in an array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

i am using a library called timer.js because I want to loop through an array, but want to have a delay between the iterations

this is a link to the library's github: https://github.com/husa/timer.js

what I did, is created a file form the min version of timer.js and linked to it in the body of html before my main js file like so:

```
<script src="./timer.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="./script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

then inside the main js file I created an array of numbers and I just want to loop through them while having an interval between the console.logs:

```
var timer = new Timer();

var nums = [1,2,3,4]

for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
  timer.start(5).on('end', function(){
    console.log(i);
  })
}
```

when I open the console log, I only get a '4' logged. Why is the for loop not working for other indexes. Also, is there any way to recreate this with a forEach function?

Thank you

Comment: thats calling `timer.start(5)` at the same time 4 times, so after `5` units of time, it should console.log 4 times, and by that time, `i` will be 4.

Comment: what does that library do that you can't do with setTimeout or setInterval ?

Comment: It is a very common mistake in JavaScript. You cannot instantiate functions inside a for loop like this, it does not work as you expect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to loop through an array, but want to have a delay between the iterations

Set the duration based on the iteration:

```
duration*iteration
```

setTimeout can achieve the delay, duration is in milliseconds, let's say 2 seconds (2000ms), and lets add 1 to the iteration so it has a delay for the first iteration:

```js
const nums = [1,2,3,4]

nums.forEach((n, i)=>{
  setTimeout(()=>(
    console.log(i)
  ), 2000*(i+1))
});
```

Comment: This will produce similar results, but it's crucial to understand that the forEach will not wait between iterations. It's simply scheduling all of the logs at once, each with a multiplied delay.

Answer (score 1):

You're running into a few common pitfalls when dealing with asynchronous code.

The first thing to realize is that your for loop is *not* waiting for each iteration to complete. It's simply invoking `timer.start(5)` four times, as quickly as it can. In order to do this, you can't use a for loop. Your best bet is to use something from the very popular [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) library instead.

The second thing to realize is that you're invoking `start(5)` on the same instance repeatedly, causing it to reset to five seconds each time. As a result, only one of your scheduled callbacks is being invoked, five seconds *after* the loop has completed. This is really less a misunderstanding of async code, and more a misunderstanding of the `timer.js` library itself. You can fix this by just creating new timers in the loops, but for your case `timer.js` is a bit overkill. You can do exactly what you want with native `setTimeout` calls.

The third thing to realize is that the callback you're sending to `on()` does not store the current value of `i`. It simply stores a reference to that variable, so any changes to that variable will ultimately be reflected in the log.

During the last iteration of the loop, the value of `i` is actually 3, not 4. This is because 4 is not `<` nums.length. So, the only callback to execute should log a 3, right?

Not so fast, though. The last thing the loop always does after each iteration is increment the value of `i`. So, `i` goes from 3 to 4, then checks if it's `<` nums.length, and since it's not, it exits. Then, five seconds later, your callback logs the value of `i`, which is now 4.

This is a property of something called a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in Javascript. I definitely recommend reading that link, because the concept is pretty crucial for using the language effectively.

Anyways, since you're probably looking for correct code here's how I would do what you're attempting, using `async` and `setTimeout`:

```
var nums = [1,2,3,4];

async.eachSeries(nums, (num, done) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(num);
        done();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: hi, can you please write a Promise version which I can try in my browser?

Comment: You can try it as-is in a browser. You just need to include this script first:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/caolan/async/master/dist/async.min.js

I'll go ahead and do one with Promises, though. I'll use a different library than `async` though, because async is mainly designed for callback-based code.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't seem to find a browser-ready promise-oriented async library. There's this  but you'd need Browserify to use it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pasync

Comment: It'd be pretty easy to wrap this small subset of async in an promise-based api, but I'm going to avoid adding that to my answer because I feel it will only add confusion.